# VBA Copy a Sheet with formatting

Tags: vba

I'm running the following code to copy and rename a worksheet but the name isn't changing for some reason. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Sub Copy()

```
Sheets("TV Indicators").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells.Copy
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Sheets("TV Indicators").Range("A3").Value
```

End Sub

Comment: In general, you can find the VBA code for many "actions" by recording a macro then looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub copier()

    Sheets("TV Indicators").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells.Copy
        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Name = Sheets("TV Indicators").Range("A3").Value
    End With
    Application.cutcopymode = false
    range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Is that okay?

Comment: Yes this works great! Is it possible to add a couple lines to end so unselect the worksheet and get out of copy/paste mode?

Comment: I can't figure out why but now the sheets are not being renamed. Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: What does cell b3 contain?

Comment: It's a dropdown list that I created using data validation. So just a string I guess.

Comment: Does it contain any illegal characters? Symbols for example?

Comment: I think I understand the problem. My sheet count changes if I add a sheet and delete it. What can I use instead of sheets.count?

Comment: @user2803302 I have updated the code to refer to `activeworksheet` instead as the new worksheet is `active` by default